# Doing cross table in hive (version 0.9)

Tags: hive

I have a table like this:

```
sport    personId
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        4
2        6
3        1
3        3
3        6
```

I would like to get a table with the count of the intersection of sports - something equivalent of the pseudo-code:

```
for sport1 in sports:
   for sport2 in sports:
       X[sport1,sport2] = count(intersect(sport1,sport2))
```

I know I to do it if I have only couple of sports:

```
select count(*) from (select * from table where sport = sport1) t1 join (select count(*) from table where sport = sport2) t2 on t1.personId = t2.personId;
```

But I would like to do generate a table for all my sports.

Note that I am on Hive 0.9, that doesn't support cross join.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a table that, for each pair of sports, lists the number of people who play both sports?

If so, you could do that in streaming hadoop and python:

- Sort by personId
- Pass sport, personId into Python
- Cache the personId, and add all the sports to a list
- Upon getting a different personId, do this:

.

```
for i, sport1 in enumerate(sports):
    for sport2 in sports[i:]:
        print '\t'.join([sport1, sport2, '1'])
```

Then `select sport1, sport2, count(*) as c group by sport1, sport2` from the intermediate table output from the streaming job.

Comment: Yes, I did the double group by and it did the trick, although it didn't output a table. I'll investigate the python reducer later.